# Artifacts on layer in one direction

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have an Ender 3.

When my printer is laying down a flat layer and is going from left to right, it lays down a nearly perfect layer. However, when that same layer is going right to left, I get artifacts.

These artifacts make a design which must tell me something but I can't think of what it could be. What would cause artifacts to appear only in one direction?

Here you can see it is currently going from right to left at a diagonal. The layer below this one was flawless!

[image: Layer showing artifacts]

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! This is a possible duplicate question, does [this](/a/8408/) answer your question?

Comment: i don't think that answers the question. The question and answer for that was due to the hot end temp and cooling fan. The issue i am having is related to the direction the printer is going, i don't think that is related. If it was a hot end or cooling fan issue, it should be present at all time regardless of direct, right?